# Sometime get 404 error on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have an issue with  Google Cloud Run, I have deloyed a web application using Cloud Run, with args '--platform=managed', '--region=us-central1'. It runs ok, but i refresh an endpoint any time on web browser, i got 404 notfound. I'm using cloudbuild.yaml in my project for deployment on Cloud Run. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: please your Dockerfile and cloudbuild.yaml you can edit your question. Also what logs you are seeing in Cloud Run? It might be that your port 8080 is not exposed correctly, or the path is not set correctly.

Comment: Hi @Pentium10,
I checked It again, My application run correct with port 8080 and i can visit my website, I find that issue happened when i deploy new version, after then some hours, everything seem run well.

Comment: It might be you're exposing the port before some of the routes are ready to receive traffic